# Javascript hash table data structure. Intersection&reduce

Tags: javascript

The question was when given multiple arrays return an array with all intersected array values.  I have read through a few solutions and I am trying to understand this hash table solution.

I am having trouble understanding this line:

```
a[propName] = a[propName] || {count:0, value: val};
```

To my understanding we are looping through each element of our subarray.  Our accumulator object is given the property name of the subarrays value.

This is where I get confused.  The value of our object property is a[propName].  I do not understand this value.  My understanding is we should make our object property the value of our subarray (making the line `a[propName]=a[propName]` into `a[propName]=propName` instead) but when I do this we are not able to count how many times the property has occurred.  I do not get why we have to put the `a[propName]` and what data structure we are accessing that is different from just using `propName`.  There obviously a difference since when I use `a[propName]` we are able to count how many times the property has occurred. If someone can thoroughly explain what is going on I'd be very grateful.

```
function intersection(){
  // convert arguments to array of arrays
  var arrays = [].slice.call(arguments);
  // create an object that tracks counts of instances and is type specific
  // so numbers and strings would not be counted as same
  var counts= arrays.reduce(function(a,c){
     // iterate sub array and count element instances
     c.forEach(function(val){
        var propName =  typeof val + '|' + val;
        // if array value not previously encountered add a new property        
        a[propName] = a[propName] || {count:0, value: val};       
        // increment count for that property
        a[propName].count++;
        console.log(a);
     });
     return a;
  },{});

  // iterate above object to return array of values where count matches total arrays length
  return Object.keys(counts).reduce(function(resArr, propName){
    if(counts[propName].count === arrays.length){
      resArr.push(counts[propName].value);
    }
    return resArr;
  },[]);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line you are pointing checks if `a[propName]` exists, and, if it not exists (so it is `undefined`) initialize it to `{count:0, value: val};`.

Let's have a closer look.

First of all, let's use more meaningful names. `a` is `accumulator`, the variable you use to keep track of everything.

At the beginning, it is an empty object.

At the first iteration of `c.forEach` it has no properties.

Therefore, given a propName like 'string|asd', it adds its first property, and `accumulator` becomes `accumulator = {'string|asd' : {count:0, value: val}};`.

Then increments the value of count.

If it finds another 'string|asd' it just increments the count, because the check `a[propName] = a[propName] || {count:0, value: val};` will just keep the prop.

```js
let a = {}

// a.c does not exist, therefore is undefined
console.log(a.c)

a.c = a.b || 1;
// a.c now is 1
console.log(a.c)

a.c = a.c || 2;
// a.c is still 1, because the `or` operator returns as soon as it finds a valid value
console.log(a.c)
```

Comment: Note that if `a[propName]` is already present and equal to 0, null, or anything else ["falsy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), it will be replaced with that object as well. That could be that is fine, but it's not strictly an existence check. You could use `a[propName] = (propName in a) || {count:0, value:val};` if the original was not the desired behavior.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan In the context of this application, it's an invariant that if `a[propName]` exists, it will always be an object. So the code doesn't need to worry about it being some other falsey value.

Comment: @Barmar Of course, but since the asker is a beginner, I felt it is worth clarifying that using `obj[propName]` for checking existence *in general* is not neccessarily sufficient.

Comment: thanks everyone.  Some reason I was thinking i was assigning a value instead of checking a conditional.  thorough explaination too thanks.  and Mike that did clarify a[propName] to me thanks.